# Compression schemes sending difference between successive samples only, what would happen if error occurs?

Tags: communication, error-correction, compression

There are multiple inginious data compression methods in which we send the difference between current and next sample rather than the actual value of the sample. This makes it possible to send the data in fraction of the actual bandwidth required to send original samples.

I have following questions:

1) How does data transfer start? i.e if we only send the difference, how do we assign value to the data at the beginning when there is no previous sample to refer to?

2) The difference between previous and current sample will usually be small but sometimes very large e.g when the scene or focus in a video changes to something different. Does this mean that small and large differences between the samples are sent using the same bandwidth? Really??

3) Error in data can occur quite easily. What if error occurs in the current "difference sample" sent across the channel? Won't this cause the error to propagate to all future samples values at the output reciever???

Answer (score 2):

If there is an error, it will propagate as you said through the whole sequence and would never stop.

Because of that there are certain key frames at certain points in time. That is a complete frame where all the data is transmitted. So the first thing that will be transmitted is a key frame, after that only the differences are transmitted for a certain amount of frames and then another key frame is inserted.

In some special cases it can happen that describing the differences from one frame to the next frame would take more space than the whole frame, so you can insert key frames at intelligent positions to save some data as well (think of a cut between two scenes).

I described this from a video point of view, as it can be imagined easily. I guess everyone stumbled upon a corrupt video where all colors would suddenly be wrong, only some contours are recognizable and after a few seconds it would suddenly all be well again (a key frame occurred).

Comment: Yes I have experienced what you have said with the video going all strange. It especially happened when I skip to a point in the video. The frames show gibberish in some places for a while but eventually it clears up.

Now my question is, since the channel is band limited and that is why we use differentual coding, how can we even send the whole frame? Won't that cause spikes in volume of data transfer and may not fit in with the channel bandwidth?

Comment: I'll be honest and say that I don't know enough about that to answer your question completely. Indeed the whole frame will probably be a spike or burst of more data. I could think of a scheme where you would compress the image with more losses, so the quality would be lower and with the next frames it would be recreated through the differences to higher quality frames maybe? I also think of progressive encoded JPEG where you can display the picture from the first few bytes on (and it gets better with every byte you load).

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How does data transfer start? i.e if we only send the difference,
>   how do we assign value to the data at the beginning when there is no
>   previous sample to refer to?

Different schemes use different methods. Some assume that the initial value is zero, so the first "difference" transmitted is based on that. Other schemes have a way of occasionally transmitting an absolute signal value instead of a difference value.

> 2) The difference between previous and current sample will usually be
>   small but sometimes very large e.g when the scene or focus in a video
>   changes to something different. Does this mean that small and large
>   differences between the samples are sent using the same bandwidth?
>   Really??

Yes. The differences are encoded using "adaptive quantization", which basically means a kind of floating-point representation that can handle a wide dynamic range with a fixed number of bits.

> 3) Error in data can occur quite easily. What if error occurs in the
>   current "difference sample" sent across the channel? Won't this cause
>   the error to propagate to all future samples values at the output
>   reciever???

Yes, which is why all practical schemes have a way of dealing with this. If the encoder occasionally transmits absolute data as described above, this functions as a "reset" mechanism that wipes out all prior errors. Other schemes have a way of gradually reducing the influence of older data, so the offsets from errors eventually decay away.

One good example of how this can work is the [ADPCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_differential_pulse-code_modulation) (Adaptive Differential Pulse-Coded Modulation) scheme used in telephony. In this scheme, the encoder includes a model of the decoder in its feedback loop, and the values that it encodes for each sample are the differences between the actual input and the predicted output of the decoder, including the variable quantization and the error decay mechanism. This ensures that the output of the actual decoder at the other end always converges towards the desired signal.

Comment: I will read more on this, however I am wondering how we can transmit the whole "video frame" or in other words, absolute data, at one time. The channel is band limited and that is why we use differential coding. Won't sending the absolute data from time to time cause spike in data rate on the channel? You wrote "Other schemes have a way of gradually reducing the influence of older data, so the offsets from errors eventually decay away." WOW that sounds quite interesting.

Comment: You can send absolute data if you allocate the bandwidth appropriately. Suppose you were sending 16-bit audio, and a compressed "difference" sample requires 4 bits. Sending one absolute sample and 15 difference samples (16 samples total) requires a total of 76 bits. For [video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.262/MPEG-2_Part_2#Video_coding), it's a bit more complicated, because a compressed I-frame (absolute data) takes a variable number of bits, so you have to vary the compression (adaptive quantization) of the P frames (difference data) in real time to make the best use of the bandwidth.

Comment: In other words, the bottom line is that if you want to mix absolute and difference data, it will require a slight increase in the average bandwidth, and the latency (time delay) for the samples coming out of the decoder will also increase.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative scheme to the "key frame" scheme or complete samples is to continually transmit a small fraction of the original sample along with the delta.

To see how this works, recognise that if you transmit only the delta, the process of reconstruction is simply integration, and errors thus accumulate over time.

If you transmit (say) (delta * 0.95 + sample * 0.05) the compression ratio is very similar to the pure delta rate, because the fraction is small compared to the delta and often partially cancels it out, and reconstruction process is equivalent to a "leaky integrator".

The effect of a bit error now attenuates over time and eventually disappears without the further complexity of embedding key frames or complete samples in the stream, or identifying them and treating them differently in the receiver.

On a [digital video compression system](http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/publications/rdreport_1984_05) (in 3 dimensions,X,Y and time) the effect was to convert a bit error into a dull shape that briefly spread down and right while fading (described on p.14); these quickly earned the name "tadpoles"...

Historical note : this scheme was successfully trialled, and [further developed](http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/publications/rdreport_1987_16), but more complex transform-based techniques (MPEG etc) offered the potential for much higher compression ratio, so they eclipsed it before its use could become widespread.